# Undertanding Javascript's prototype keyword and implementation

Tags: javascript

I'm new to web-development, coming from C/C++/x86. For all my efforts to circumvent it, it appears as though I'll need to use Javascript (surprise!).

Well, if I'm going to have to use it, I might as well understand whats going on. This has been difficult, since I'm used to being able to easily map C/C++ down to x86/x86_64 to figure out what's happening. Not to mention, Javascript is an entirely different paradigm to get accustomed to.

So, *what is this **prototype** keyword, and how is this prototypical inheritance implemented?*

After reading a few highly touted books and guides, I'll I've seen is examples. Every object (save the global object) has a prototype, which is another object. There has to be a very simple mechanism operating in the background on how these all these objects are linked.

I don't need to hear any more of "a new object inherits the properties of an old object" wishy-wash stuff you tell 12 year olds. For example, I know how C++'s virtual table works to understand how virtual functions work - everything makes perfect sense.

So, how does does Javascript use prototyping?

Thank you.

Comment: So read the V8 source. And bear in mind not all implementations will implement it the same way. So far it sounds like you're over-thinking it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Comment: @DaveNewton I can't help it. Not knowing what's going on in the background doesn't seem.. right.

Comment: @gone That's fine, if you have the time. But every engine will implement it in its own way. The *behavior* is what's important. Another option is to implement your own JavaScript as a learning exercise; the bulk of it is straight forward.

Comment: I'd say go read the ECMAScript draft. It's what all the JavaScript VM's are written based off.

http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-4.3.5 , http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-4.2.1

Comment: The "manual": http://es5.github.io/, http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#interface-prototype-object

Comment: This is one of those questions where everyone gives you the most bullshit answer to. Prototype is just a way to add a property to all future and current instances of a type. Plain and simple.

Comment: @Nick Which says nothing about the implementation, which seems to be what he's asking.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `prototype` properties as `static`. `prototype` is just an access word, it means nothing except assign properties to, or write over, the Object you are accessing with the word `prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

`prototype` is a language construct of Javascript. It's JavaScript's approach to inheritance.

In javascript (until ECMAScript6 but that's a different subject) there are not true `classes`. Instead we create instances of objects, and we can create child instances of those objects using the `new` keyword. For instance:

```
var parent = function() {};
parent.prototype.lastName = "Flynn";
var child = new parent();
console.log(child.lastName); //Outputs "Flynn"
```

Also, interestingly:

```
parent.prototype.nationality = "American";
console.log(child.nationality); //Outputs "American"
```